# sql return percentage from rows by column value

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns: Name, A, B.

The names in 'Name' repeat many times.

I wish, for each name in Name, return the sum of values in in 'A' dievided by the sum of values in 'B'.

For example:

```
Name    A    B 
---------------
'fds'   5    4
'fds'   3    6
'keo'   3    4
```

I want to get this table:

```
Name    Percentage
-------------------
'fds'      0.8
'kep'      0.75
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `group by`:

```
    select Name, cast(sum(A) as float)/cast(sum(B) as float) Percentage
    from TableName
    group by Name
```

Answer (score 1):

What are the data types of `A` and `B`?  In most databases and under most circumstances, this will work:

```
select name, sum(A) / sum(B) as ratio
from t
group by name;
```

It is safer to write this to prevent division by `0`:

```
select name, sum(A) / nullif(sum(B), 0) as ratio
from t
group by name;
```

Some databases do integer division if the columns are both integers (of any sort).  In that case, I often just multiply by 1.0:

```
select name, sum(A) * 1.0 / nullif(sum(B), 0) as ratio
from t
group by name;
```

Note that I renamed the column to `ratio`.  Traditionally, `percentages` go from 0 to 100 and not from 0 to 1.